# ATmega communication with I2C + extender or with ENC28J60 ethernet module?

Tags: i2c, communication, ethernet

I want to communicate between ATmega328P µC's over 'long distance'. The ATmega µC's will be 5m to 20m apart and the total length of the chain will be around 50m with up to 10 ATmega's in one chain.

What would be the better option:
Making a I2C bus with P82B715P or P82B96P bus extenders or making an ethernet bus with ENC28J60 modules?

Cost and space are important. All modules also need to be powered over the data cable.

At first I thought to go for the P82B715P modules, connected with 4x2 Cat5e cable, but after reading a lot of negative blog posts on long-distance I2C, I started to doubt. Hence my question.

Comment: If you have the option, then go for Ethernet. I2C is OK for onboard master-slave communication. Master-master and long distance can of course be done with I2C, but I guess there is a good reason why you don't see that very often.

Comment: Are those the only two options? CAN, RS485, and even RS232 and plain TTL seem obvious alternatives.

Comment: I need multi-master configuration. In fact every module needs to be capable to be master and slave. In that scenario, is CAN, RS485 an option?

Comment: CAN from physical layer and up to various data protocols are made for multimaster setups. RS485 is a physical layer, not very useful for multimaster. But if you look into the  SAE J1708 automotive standard, there is a way to make RS485 work with multiple masters. CAN and Ethernet handles the collissions in the protocol (resends, priority, arbitration etc) and the physical layer doesn't get upset by several drivers pulling the lines.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't need to be a high-speed link, RS485 or CAN would be your best bet. For RS485, transceivers are cheap and easily connected electrically, but need a bit of work on the protocol side to make reliable, while CAN transceivers are a bit more expensive but take over the bus arbitration work for you.

I'd get a CAN controller that can be connected to the ATmega via SPI. Make sure the /CS for the controller has a pull-up resistor (pull-down if it is active-high, but it won't be) so it is inactive while you program the ATmega, since this also uses the same pins.

Both of these use differential signalling to minimize the impact of interference, which is likely to be severe in a cable this long.

I'd use a four-stranded cable, with a supply voltage that is way too high (e.g. 12V) and individual switch-mode regulators on each unit to get the supply voltages required; that way, you minimize voltage drop over the cable and give yourself quite a bit of headroom so the device at the other end of the cable still gets enough voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Todays 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet is NOT a chainable, you have to implement two separate interfaces in each device and that is a lot of extra work in your AVR.

You could however use a 16 port switch and run a separate Etherenet cable to each unit. This gets you to one interface in each AVR.
If you use POE, then you could easily power all the units. The cost for this is somewhat high, so I anticipate not an ideal solution for you. 
I2C is maximum 10 meter cable length, so you would again need to create multiple interfaces separately buffering the cable lengths.

Perhaps the best way to approach this would be to try:

1. ESP8266 with an external coax antenna connector. These could be connected to a coax cable as your chain. Power could be fed over the coax providing you check the coupling circuits for the ESP8266. You need to ac couple any termination resistors and may need ferrite beads on the power connections.
2. Use an NRF24L01+ with a PA and external antenna connector. This does work well with a coax cable between units for both power and signal (though don't forget to ac couple the terminator resistors you use).

Comment: Is there a name for this "radio over the wire" trick?

Comment: Historically this would be MoCA or you get Ethernet over Powerline adapters or Ethernet over Coax.